# Clojure Method Missing

Tags: java, ruby, clojure, lisp

Does anybody know how to implement method_missing (à la Ruby) in Clojure?
E.g.

```
(defn method_missing [name & args]
     (foo name args))
```

It would be very useful for a DSL, if used correctly.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In what cases would you want this function to be invoked?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Ruby, `method_missing` is one of the primary constructs for metaprogramming. It's tightly bound to Ruby's object oriented structure, dynamically creating methods in a class from 'metaclasses'. This can be done because in Ruby classes are objects too.

Since Clojure is a functional language, mimicking this Rubyism makes little sense. However, one of the basic idioms of Lisps (such as Clojure), is that code is data: and as code can generate data, it can generate code also. The primary way to do this metaprogramming in Lisp is macros.

I'd suggest reading more about macros and their dos and don'ts. Be advised though that just like in Ruby, dynamically generated code is generally harder to debug and maintain. Often clever use of other functional idioms can be a better structural solution.

Comment: I agree with most of this, but I object to the claim that dynamically-generated code is hard to debug or maintain. Macros are a great boon to simplification and maintainability, provided they are used tastefully.

Comment: Just wanted to point out when to use macros should be carefully considered, and when you can do something with normal functions this should be preferred.

Comment: Having come from Ruby myself, I found it can take a while to grasp the power of function composition. Using macros to work around this  can be counterproductive.

Comment: I haven't had much experience in Clojure, so I'm still getting used to the LISP-ish ideas, such as macros. I definitely see how someone could misuse their powers now. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You could create a macro that would wrap function calls in a try-catch block that would catch this sort of exception.

e.g. Something like

```
(with-default-method [fxn args default] ...)
```

would expand to

```
(try (fxn args) (catch java.lang.IllegalArgumentException _) (finally default))
```

The above is mostly hand-waving, because I don't think that this is a good idea at all: it's abuse of the exception system, and I think it'll do unexpected things.

I'm not a Ruby person, but I get the feeling that this feature is baked into that language; in java, and by extension clojure, you'd have to try and bolt this on, and it wouldn't be pretty.